# Passing variables to different classes on different files

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to create software that requires a variable to be passed from a function into a class, like this:

```
def goToAddingAClass(self):
    className = self.CreateNewClassEntry.get()
    root2 = Toplevel(self.master)
    NextWindow = AddingAClassPage.AddingAClass(root2)
```

...

```
from HomePage import *

class InputtingStudentInformation():
    def __init__(self, master):
        titleLabel(master, 'Adding a Class ' + className, labelBackground())
```

I have removed a lot of the code for simplicity. The first file is called HomePage and the second is InputtingStudentInformationPage. However, I am not sure how to get the variable "className" into the second class. I have tried importing all from Homepage as shown but get an error saying

```
global name 'className' is not defined
```

How can I pass variables between classes on different files?

Comment: `className` is local variable and exists only in `goToAddingAClass()`. Maybe you shoude use `global` or rather `return className` and `global_className = goToAddingAClass()` then `InputtingStudentInformation(global_className)`

Comment: your question is confusing. In those 8 lines of code you have several things that look like class names (`InputtingStudentInformation`, and maybe`AddingAClassPage`, and maybe `AddingAClass`, The problem seems to be in getting a variable into `InputtingStudentInformation` yet you don't show the code where you create that class.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to get information from one class into another is to pass it in. Often this takes the form of another parameter in the constructor:

```
class InputtingStudentInformation():
    def __init__(self, master, className):
        titleLabel(master, 'Adding a Class ' + className, labelBackground())
...
className = self.CreateNewClassEntry.get()
something = InputtingStudentInformation(master, className)
```